# Image rotation by Matlab without using imrotate

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation

I am trying to rotate an image with Matlab without using imrotate function. I actually made it by using transformation matrix.But it is not good enough.The problem is, the rotated image is "sliding".Let me tell you with pictures.

This is my image which I want to rotate:

[image]

But when I rotate it ,for example 45 degrees, it becomes this:

[image]

I am asking why this is happening.Here is my code,is there any mathematical or programming mistakes about it?

```
image=torso;

%image padding
[Rows, Cols] = size(image); 
Diagonal = sqrt(Rows^2 + Cols^2); 
RowPad = ceil(Diagonal - Rows) + 2;
ColPad = ceil(Diagonal - Cols) + 2;
imagepad = zeros(Rows+RowPad, Cols+ColPad);
imagepad(ceil(RowPad/2):(ceil(RowPad/2)+Rows-1),ceil(ColPad/2):(ceil(ColPad/2)+Cols-1)) = image;

degree=45;

%midpoints
midx=ceil((size(imagepad,1)+1)/2);
midy=ceil((size(imagepad,2)+1)/2);

imagerot=zeros(size(imagepad));

%rotation
for i=1:size(imagepad,1)
    for j=1:size(imagepad,2)

         x=(i-midx)*cos(degree)-(j-midy)*sin(degree);
         y=(i-midx)*sin(degree)+(j-midy)*cos(degree);
         x=round(x)+midx;
         y=round(y)+midy;

         if (x>=1 && y>=1)
              imagerot(x,y)=imagepad(i,j); % k degrees rotated image         
         end

    end
end

 figure,imagesc(imagerot);
 colormap(gray(256));
```

Comment: Have you tried using radians instead of degrees?

Comment: Actually I did.But nothing has changed.The rotated picture is right but its coordinates.

Comment: As @Junuxx pointed out, `cos` and `sin` work with radians, not degrees. If you want to use degrees, you should use `cosd` and `sind` instead.

Comment: Thank you but I tried it too.Still the same.Is there any mathematical mistake in my equations?

Comment: Is there a reason you add 2 to the padding? `ceil(Diagonal - Rows) + 2`

Comment: @Moondra I wanted to put extra 1 left 1 right, 1 up 1 down padding to the image. You don't have to use it, if I remember right.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason you have holes in your image is because you are computing the location in `imagerot` of each pixel in `imagepad`.  You need to do the computation the other way around.  That is, for each pixel in `imagerot` interpolate in `imagepad`.  To do this, you just need to apply the inverse transform, which in the case of a rotation matrix is just the transpose of the matrix (just change the sign on each `sin` and translate the other way).

Loop over pixels in `imagerot`:

```
imagerot=zeros(size(imagepad)); % midx and midy same for both

for i=1:size(imagerot,1)
    for j=1:size(imagerot,2)

         x= (i-midx)*cos(rads)+(j-midy)*sin(rads);
         y=-(i-midx)*sin(rads)+(j-midy)*cos(rads);
         x=round(x)+midx;
         y=round(y)+midy;

         if (x>=1 && y>=1 && x<=size(imagepad,2) && y<=size(imagepad,1))
              imagerot(i,j)=imagepad(x,y); % k degrees rotated image         
         end

    end
end
```

Also note that your `midx` and `midy` need to be calculated with `size(imagepad,2)` and `size(imagepad,1)` respectively, since the first dimension refers to the number of rows (height) and the second to width.

NOTE: The same approach applies when you decide to adopt an interpolation scheme other than nearest neighbor, as in Rody's example with linear interpolation.

**EDIT**: I'm assuming you are using a loop for demonstrative purposes, but in practice there is no need for loops.  Here's an example of nearest neighbor interpolation (what you are using), keeping the same size image, but you can modify this to produce a larger image that includes the whole source image:

```
imagepad = imread('peppers.png');
[nrows ncols nslices] = size(imagepad);
midx=ceil((ncols+1)/2);
midy=ceil((nrows+1)/2);

Mr = [cos(pi/4) sin(pi/4); -sin(pi/4) cos(pi/4)]; % e.g. 45 degree rotation

% rotate about center
[X Y] = meshgrid(1:ncols,1:nrows);
XYt = [X(:)-midx Y(:)-midy]*Mr;
XYt = bsxfun(@plus,XYt,[midx midy]);

xout = round(XYt(:,1)); yout = round(XYt(:,2)); % nearest neighbor!
outbound = yout<1 | yout>nrows | xout<1 | xout>ncols;
zout=repmat(cat(3,1,2,3),nrows,ncols,1); zout=zout(:);
xout(xout<1) = 1; xout(xout>ncols) = ncols;
yout(yout<1) = 1; yout(yout>nrows) = nrows;
xout = repmat(xout,[3 1]); yout = repmat(yout,[3 1]);
imagerot = imagepad(sub2ind(size(imagepad),yout,xout,zout(:))); % lookup
imagerot = reshape(imagerot,size(imagepad));
imagerot(repmat(outbound,[1 1 3])) = 0; % set background value to [0 0 0] (black)
```

To modify the above to linear interpolation, compute the 4 neighboring pixels to each coordinate in `XYt` and perform a weighted sum using the fractional components product as the weights. I'll leave that as an exercise, since it would only serve to bloat my answer further beyond the scope of your question.  :)

Comment: Thank you,that really worked.So I was trying to find the wrong (x,y)'s

Comment: May I ask one more thing? After finding x and y,why do we adding midx,midy? I am stucked at math of this rotation

Comment: @Zapdos - To rotate about the center of the image, you have to subtract the centroid, transform, then add it back in.

Answer (score 13):

The method you are using (rotate by sampling) is the fastest and simplest, but also the least accurate.

Rotation by area mapping, as given below ([this](http://www.leptonica.com/rotation.html) is a good reference), is much better at preserving color.

But: note that this will only work on greyscale/RGB images, but NOT on colormapped images like the one you seem to be using.

```
image = imread('peppers.png');

figure(1), clf, hold on
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(image);

degree = 45;

switch mod(degree, 360)
    % Special cases
    case 0
        imagerot = image;
    case 90
        imagerot = rot90(image);
    case 180
        imagerot = image(end:-1:1, end:-1:1);
    case 270
        imagerot = rot90(image(end:-1:1, end:-1:1));

    % General rotations
    otherwise

        % Convert to radians and create transformation matrix
        a = degree*pi/180;
        R = [+cos(a) +sin(a); -sin(a) +cos(a)];

        % Figure out the size of the transformed image
        [m,n,p] = size(image);
        dest = round( [1 1; 1 n; m 1; m n]*R );
        dest = bsxfun(@minus, dest, min(dest)) + 1;
        imagerot = zeros([max(dest) p],class(image));

        % Map all pixels of the transformed image to the original image
        for ii = 1:size(imagerot,1)
            for jj = 1:size(imagerot,2)
                source = ([ii jj]-dest(1,:))*R.';
                if all(source >= 1) && all(source <= [m n])

                    % Get all 4 surrounding pixels
                    C = ceil(source);
                    F = floor(source);

                    % Compute the relative areas
                    A = [...
                        ((C(2)-source(2))*(C(1)-source(1))),...
                        ((source(2)-F(2))*(source(1)-F(1)));
                        ((C(2)-source(2))*(source(1)-F(1))),...
                        ((source(2)-F(2))*(C(1)-source(1)))];

                    % Extract colors and re-scale them relative to area
                    cols = bsxfun(@times, A, double(image(F(1):C(1),F(2):C(2),:)));

                    % Assign                     
                    imagerot(ii,jj,:) = sum(sum(cols),2);

                end
            end
        end        
end

subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(imagerot);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Good idea for special case handling.  Note that `rot90(A,K)` will do `K` 90 rotations at once, using the same approach for 180 as yours but then a transpose and a flip for 270.

Answer (score 8):

Rotates colored image according to angle given by user  without any cropping of image in matlab.

Output of this program is similar to output of inbuilt command "imrotate" .This program dynamically creates background according to angle input given by user.By using rotation matrix and origin shifting, we get relation between coordinates of initial and final image.Using relation between coordinates of initial and final image, we now map the intensity values for each pixel.

```
img=imread('img.jpg'); 

[rowsi,colsi,z]= size(img); 

angle=45;

rads=2*pi*angle/360;  

%calculating array dimesions such that  rotated image gets fit in it exactly.
% we are using absolute so that we get  positve value in any case ie.,any quadrant.

rowsf=ceil(rowsi*abs(cos(rads))+colsi*abs(sin(rads)));                      
colsf=ceil(rowsi*abs(sin(rads))+colsi*abs(cos(rads)));                     

% define an array withcalculated dimensionsand fill the array  with zeros ie.,black
C=uint8(zeros([rowsf colsf 3 ]));

%calculating center of original and final image
xo=ceil(rowsi/2);                                                            
yo=ceil(colsi/2);

midx=ceil((size(C,1))/2);
midy=ceil((size(C,2))/2);

% in this loop we calculate corresponding coordinates of pixel of A 
% for each pixel of C, and its intensity will be  assigned after checking
% weather it lie in the bound of A (original image)
for i=1:size(C,1)
    for j=1:size(C,2)                                                       

         x= (i-midx)*cos(rads)+(j-midy)*sin(rads);                                       
         y= -(i-midx)*sin(rads)+(j-midy)*cos(rads);                             
         x=round(x)+xo;
         y=round(y)+yo;

         if (x>=1 && y>=1 && x<=size(img,1) &&  y<=size(img,2) ) 
              C(i,j,:)=img(x,y,:);  
         end

    end
end

imshow(C);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.

this is fastest way that you can do.
[image: this is the output]

```
img = imread('Koala.jpg');

theta = pi/10;
rmat = [
cos(theta) sin(theta) 0
-sin(theta) cos(theta) 0
0           0          1];

mx = size(img,2);
my = size(img,1);
corners = [
    0  0  1
    mx 0  1
    0  my 1
    mx my 1];
new_c = corners*rmat;

T = maketform('affine', rmat);   %# represents translation
img2 = imtransform(img, T, ...
    'XData',[min(new_c(:,1)) max(new_c(:,1))],...
    'YData',[min(new_c(:,2)) max(new_c(:,2))]);
subplot(121), imshow(img);
subplot(122), imshow(img2);
```

Comment: Um, the point was to learn and do this without the transform functions, whether it's `imtransform` or `imrotate`. But yeah, this is how you would do it for real so +1 for contributing that.

Comment: This uses the image processing toolbox.  The point is to perform this **without it**.  This answer is also deprecated as `maketform` and `imtransform` are no longer recommended as the official functions for doing this.  `affine2d` and `imwarp` now are.