# Crop a rotated image based on the object bounding box - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Why I can not crop the rotated image based on the object (jet) bounding box and is there a more efficient way to do it?
Based on previous question: [Image single background color - Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56915143/image-single-background-color-matlab)

Code:

```
close all;
clear;
clc;

url='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/T/i/o/c/X/Q/airplane-md.png';
rgbImage = imread(url);
I = rgb2gray(rgbImage);

BI = imbinarize(I);
LI = bwlabel(BI);
mea = regionprops(LI, 'Orientation');
RI = imrotate(rgbImage, -mea(1).Orientation,'loose');
imshow(RI);

% Replace all black pixels with white 
inds = sum(RI,3)==0;
RI_new = RI;
RI_new(repmat(inds,1,1,3))=255;
imshow(RI_new);
title('RI new');

% Crop rotated image 
RI_newGray = rgb2gray(RI_new);
BI_newGray = imbinarize(RI_newGray);
LI_new = bwlabel(BI_newGray);
LI_new= bwareaopen(LI_new, 50);
bbmea = regionprops(LI_new, 'BoundingBox');
rect = bbmea.BoundingBox; 
RI_newGray = imcrop(RI_new, rect); 
imshow(RI_newGray);
title('crop RI new');
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code you posted? How does that behaviour differ from what you intended to happen? Please be specific about defining the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
bbmea = regionprops(LI_new, 'BoundingBox');
```

With:

```
bbmea = regionprops(~LI_new, 'BoundingBox');
```

#### Explanation:

The problem is that `regionprops` calculates the group of the none-zero elements, in a black and white logical image the function calculates the groups of ones which are the white pixel. To calculate the bounding-box of the black pixels you can invert the image.

Using `bbmea = regionprops(LI_new, 'BoundingBox');`:

[image: Using LI_new]

Using `bbmea = regionprops(~LI_new, 'BoundingBox');`:

[image: Using ~LI_new]